# External drive not detected

Tags: 13.10, external-hdd

I just installed ubuntu 13.10. When i plug in my external hard drive to access my files, it is not detected. I have no such problem when i was using windows 7.

is there any solution to this kind of problem?

Any help would be helpful :)

```
$ dmesg
usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2339
usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 1-5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
usb 1-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 152D203380B6
usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi2 : usb-storage 1-5:1.0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60011642880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7296 cylinders, total 117210240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002cef9
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   113035263    56516608   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       113037310   117209087     2085889    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       113037312   117209087     2085888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Connect the drive. Give us the output of `dmesg`. Then give us the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: Please add this to your first post and do some formatting. Or would you like to get information from that?

Comment: how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by loading the usb-storage module again

```
$> modprobe usb-storage
```

Then unplugging and re-plugging the USB drive.